# Drive 6Vdc relay ( with coil resistance 68ohms ) with 20mA current source

Tags: relay, resistance, boost, current-source, 4-20ma

I have a current source of **4-20mA** and I need this to drive a **6Vdc** relay.

I could not use passive Current to Voltage converter since the relay coil have  resistance of **68 ohms** and the voltage drops at output if the relay is connected.

Is there any compensating circuit for this issue?

Comment: your information is incomplete ... how long does the relay have to stay energized?

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to have enough current at the low end to drive the relay, even with a boosting circuit. Is this an instrument current loop? It really isn't designed to drive relays... Can you use this into some kind of process meter that is externally powered to drive the relay?

Comment: What is the maximum resistance your 4-20MA current source can drive?

Comment: A 6V relay with a coil resistance of 68 ohms needs 88 ma.  Thus your current source is not sufficient.

Comment: @jsotola Relay need to be energised as longs as it meet certain condition decided in the program in controller.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's a 4-20ma current loop. Is there any op amp or other circuit designs to implement this?

Comment: @BruceAbbott It's current loop and usually I use passive converter (500 ohm resistor) to convert current to voltage.

Comment: 500 Ohms x 20mA = 10V.You might be able to operate a 12V relay with >=500 Ohm coil from this, but not your 6V 68 Ohm; relay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20mA at 20V (a reasonable maximum assuming a typical 24V power supply) is 400mW. Your relay takes 530mW, so even with 100% efficiency it's dubious.

At 4mA it's not on the same planet.

If you really require a relay, consider using a telecom-style latching relay that can change position with a brief (tens of ms) pulse and then draws no coil current at all.